# How to prevent method override warning in WebStorm editor

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webstorm

I'm pretty new to Javascript, and was copying the code from a tutorial into WebStorm so I could mess around with it, but I ran into a problem with the code below. 
 WebStorm alerted me with a message saying "overrides element in HTMLImageElement" on the 7th line (cat.onload). How can I navigate around this by not overriding the onload element?
 Any help would be appreciated.

```
<canvas id="e" width="177" height="113"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cat = new Image();
cat.src = "images/cat.png";
cat.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(cat, 0, 0);
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebStorm, but you could try with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)?

Comment: Your code is correct and I think WebStrom is probably just warning you that you're overriding the onload method of the image object but that's no problem. Check your web browser console for errors and you won't see any errors for your code.

Comment: @AWolf you are right, I do not see any errors, however the image is not being displayed on the canvas. There must be something else I am missing.

Comment: I have tested your code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/6ex37k1a/) and it's working there.

Comment: @AWolf, I got it work now. Thanks for that example!